# Image slideshow with zoom transition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an image slideshow with a fade in, zoom effect, and then fade out.

It appears to work initially, but after I've left it running a while in the background, it gets all jumbled up and out of sync (and multiple elements get the element style `display: block` at the same time).

Here's the code. I'm using CSS for the zooming transition effect.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kcyhcwh0/

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow-zoom">
  <div class="slideshow-zoom-slide">
    <div class="slideshow-zoom-image" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/RLP60uQ.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-zoom-slide">
    <div class="slideshow-zoom-image" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/HA4SI3J.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-zoom-slide">
    <div class="slideshow-zoom-image" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/yWNrSmE.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow-zoom-slide">
    <div class="slideshow-zoom-image" style="background-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/kP5wJ1u.jpg)"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


#slideshow-zoom {
  background-color: #232323;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

  .slideshow-zoom-slide {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &.active {
      transition: all 5s;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      }

    .slideshow-zoom-image {
      display: none;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;

    }
    &:first-child .slideshow-zoom-image {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){

  // vars
  var $ssSlides = $('.slideshow-zoom-slide');
  var $ssImages = $('.slideshow-zoom-image');
  var ssSlideCount = $ssSlides.length;

  var i = 0;
  var ssSlide = 1;
  setInterval( function () {

    if (ssSlide > ssSlideCount) {
      ssSlide = 1;
    }

    var $ssSlide = $ssSlides.eq(ssSlide-1);
    var $ssImage = $ssImages.eq(ssSlide-1);

    if (i > 0) {
      $ssImages.hide();
    }

    $ssSlides.removeClass('active');
    $ssSlide.addClass('active');

    $ssImage.fadeIn(150, "linear").delay(4500).fadeOut(350, "linear");

    ssSlide++; i++;

  }, 5000);

});
```

Any ideas on what's going wrong? Or a better way of achieving the same thing?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by it getting all jumbled up? How long are you leaving the page open in the background until you see this issue? I left your Fiddle open for almost 10 min and it looks and functions the same

Comment: Probably over an hour in a separate browser tab. It was as if the styles the js were applying to the elements weren't going through the full cycle of `display block`, `change opacity`, `display none` (some got stuck on `display block`. And also started overlapping eachother.

Comment: Hmm are you able to reproduce it consistently? I left your JS Fiddle open in my browser all night and everything looked normal in the morning.